# Tkinter: how can i get frame in canvas to expand to the size of the canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

i've been trying to get this tkinter frame to fill to the side, i've tried adding in expand but that would screw up the scrollbar

[Why wont this fill to the right?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wC7W.png)

This is the parent frame

```
self.frame_right.rowconfigure(0, weight=2)
    self.frame_right.rowconfigure(1, weight=8)

    self.frame_right.columnconfigure((0, 1), weight=1)
    self.frame_right.columnconfigure(2, weight=0)

    self.frame_info = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=self.frame_right)
    self.frame_info.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=4, pady=20, padx=20, sticky="nsew")
    # ============ frame_info ============
    self.frame_info.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    self.frame_info.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.frame_info.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
```

This is the code that creates the layout

```
def checkhotel(self, hotel1, hotel2):
    if hotel1 == "Select a hotel" or hotel2 == "Select a hotel":
        errormessage(self, "Hotel not selected")
    elif hotel1 not in allHotels or hotel2 not in allHotels:
        errormessage(self, "Hotel does not exist in database")

    else:
        self.graphcanvas = customtkinter.CTkCanvas(master=self.frame_info, background="#333333", highlightthickness=0)
        self.graphcanvas.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=20, pady=20, sticky="nsew")
        self.ctk_scrollbar = customtkinter.CTkScrollbar(master=self.frame_info, command=self.graphcanvas.yview,
                                                        scrollbar_color="white", background="grey")
        self.ctk_scrollbar.grid(row=1, column=4, sticky="ns")

        # connect textbox scroll event to CTk scrollbar
        self.graphcanvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.ctk_scrollbar.set)
        self.frame_graphs = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=self.graphcanvas)
        self.secondframeid = self.graphcanvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.frame_graphs, anchor="nw")
        self.graphcanvas.bind("<Configure>",
                              lambda event: self.graphcanvas.configure(scrollregion=self.graphcanvas.bbox("all")))

        #expand window
        getcompreddata(self, hotel1, hotel2)
```

i've tried using column span and expand for binding too, however, it screws up the scrollbar

```
def plt_freq_neg_word(self, dataframe, hotelcolumn):
    # highest negative sentiment reviews (with more than 5 words)
    NEG_BE_reviews_df = dataframe[dataframe["nb_words"] >= 5].sort_values("neg", ascending=False)[
        ["review_clean", "neg"]].head()

    all_words = ' '.join([word for word in NEG_BE_reviews_df['review_clean']])
    tokenized_words = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(all_words)
    words = nltk.word_tokenize(all_words)
    fd = FreqDist(words)
    top_10 = fd.most_common(10)

    negativeFig = plt.Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=75)
    ax2 = negativeFig.add_subplot(111)
    line2 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(negativeFig, self.frame_graphs)
    line2.get_tk_widget().grid(row=4, column=hotelcolumn, padx=10, pady=10, columnspan=2)
    fdist = pd.Series(dict(top_10))
    sns.set_theme(style="ticks", )
    sns.barplot(y=fdist.index, x=fdist.values, color='green', ax=ax2).set(
        title="Top 10 Most Frequent word from Negative Review")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could try `line2.get_tk_widget().grid(row=4, column=hotelcolumn, padx=10, pady=10, sticky='ew')`, but without a [mre] it is just a guess.

Comment: @Thingamabobs unfortunately it doesn't work :/ thanks tho!

Comment: Please try to add just a single block of code to your question that will reproduce the problem.

Comment: It looks like the relevant part is how you grid `frame_graphs` but you didn't include that part if code. Please follow the advice of @BryanOakley

Comment: Try this self.ctk_scrollbar.grid(row=1, column=4, sticky="nswe"). You could set all sticky=nswe.